# How to make a cell reference function

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Nowe

X = 1

For i = 1 to 5
If Cells (i, X).Value = "What" Then

Cells (i+1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I am showing an error on this snippet: "If Cells (i, **X**).Value = "What" Then"
I would like to make a reference but as functions

Comment: What do you mean by "make a reference as function"? I'm sorry, I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: Remove the space between Cells and the opening bracket.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to run your code, the only error I got was related to not declaring `x` and `i` variables.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Nowe()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    x = 1
    
    For i = 1 To 5
    If Cells(i, x).Value = "What" Then
    
    Cells(i + 1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```